# How can I measure the computational complexity of my Convolutional Neural Network Model?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, profiling, code-complexity

I have to evaluate my CNN model for Semantic Segmentation (when predicting) in terms of **computational complexity**, **memory use** and **processing time**. I work with Python (Keras).

Is there a way to count the number of operations performed in each layer or at least in the whole model?

I was taking a look to profiling libraries such as CProfile, but honestly, I am not sure of what I am getting.

Any help, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by _computational complexity_, exactly? _memory use and processing time_ are simply a matter of benchmarking and profiling, there are already plenty of resources on the subject.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment! I might be using the wrong terminology, What I want is to estimate the number of basic operations (addition, multiplication, variable assignation...) performed by my CNN model in the prediction stage. I think this is usually expressed by big-O notation.